# displaying one category on one page

Tags: categories, pages

i have been trying to display all posts of similar category on one page (best ones)

[image]

work fine with is_home() but isn't working with is_page() or is_category().

Answer (score 0):

If it works with `is_home()` then I think it is just a problem with your slug.

Have you tried to check the `is_page` by it ID directly?

Something like this should return

`/*
 * Returns true when the Pages displayed is either post ID 1,
 * or post_name "top-best", or post_title "Top Best".
 * Note: the array ability was added in version 2.5.
 */
is_page( array( 1, 'top-best', 'Top Best' ) );`

Source : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/#comment-370